# Does React Native support different assets for iPhone vs iPad?

Tags: react-native

In regular iOS native development, in XCode, for each image, you can set 1x 2x 3x for iPhone and 1x 2x for iPad.

It seems like React Native only allows you to set 1x 2x 3x for assets, without differentiating between phones or tablets.

Does React Native support anything similar? 
For iPhones, it is serving my images correctly (i.e. 3x for iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X). However, for iPads, it seems like it is always serving 2x images, which are too low-res.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load images directly from a Xcode asset catalogs and also you can detect if the platform is an ipad or an iphone( by calling Platform.isPad ). So, you could try creating platform specific assets in xcode and also load them by platform in react-native.

Check the Images From Hybrid App's Resources tag:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html